# Bootstrap image is not being static when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Guys i am early stage in development of website. I made this image in photoshop and applied a logo in website with navbar for a test. I am not getting results right because when i zoom in image is blurry and it is being so big I want it to be same size even when i zoom in. Please Help

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="text-center justify-content-center">
    <img src="Untitled-1.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light justify-content-center">
        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">CERTIFICATES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
<style>

.nav-link
{
  color: black;
}

.navbar-nav > li
{
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
}

.nav-link:hover
{
  color: wheat;
}

</style>

</html>
```

I want logo to be of the same size when I zoom in but the logo is getting bigger when I zoom in as you can see in above picture.
[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the design of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added screenshots.